# ENCS-5408 (default-gw for mgmt & wan)

Tags: cisco, nfv

I have a "NFVIS" ENCS-5408 router whose WAN port is connected via /30 address.

Now, this device doesn't seem as intuitive as regular IOS where I set default route for different networks.

How do I set different default-gw so that both mgmt and wan routes are functional?

Thanks.

**** Version ****

```
Cisco Enterprise Network Function Virtualization Infrastructure Software (NFVIS)

NFVIS Version: 3.6.2-FC3
```

**** Current routes ****

```
system settings hostname nfvis
system settings mgmt ip address 10.70.0.50 255.255.255.0
system settings wan ip address 192.168.200.128 255.255.255.252
system settings default-gw 10.70.0.1
networks network wan-net
 bridge wan-br
!
networks network lan-net
 bridge lan-br
!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is like inception as in you have to activate router-vm inside the router appliance.

like

### 1 web portal

[image]

### 2 then vnc the good old ios

[image]